# why is my focus() event not firing in my PWA?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, focus, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've never not been able to find an answer to a question on the stack, but I have one now I can't resolve.

I have just converted my company intranet to a PWA.  It's running nicely on my android phone, but there is a problem.  I have an sms and phone component which open in separate windows.  This works great on the desktop, as I just switch focus() if the window is already open, or open a window if it's not.  On the mobile PWA, if the window is not open, it opens properly, and from the child window I can refocus back to the opener by name.  However, if I try to get back to the child window from the parent (opener) window, it doesn't work, and can't figure out why.

Here is the code:

```
// this is the parent
function popupnr(mylink, windowname, refocus) {
// open the window with blank url
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 700) {
    thewidth = 700;
}
else {
    thewidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
}
openspecs = 'height=' + document.documentElement.clientHeight + ',width=' + thewidth + ',toolbar=1,menubar=1,location=1,status=0';
var mywin = window.open('', windowname, openspecs);

// if we opened the window
if (!refocus || mywin.closed || (!mywin.document.URL) || (mywin.document.URL.indexOf("about") == 0)) {
    transfer = setTimeout(function(){
        mywin.location = mylink;
    }, 400);
}
else if (refocus) {
    mywin.focus();
}

// return the window
return mywin;
}
```

Here is what I use to focus back on the opener:

```
bossname = 'waterbase';
window.name = bossname;

// this is the child window:  open on parent, or just focus if the current page of the parent is the target is the same
function popupnr_motherf(mylink) {

mywin = bossname;

if (opener.document.URL.indexOf(mylink) == -1) {
  window.open(mylink,bossname).focus();
}
else {
  window.open('',bossname).focus();
}

}
```

I think this might have something to do with the service-worker, as I already had to add the 400ms delay that you see in the code above when opening the window the first time, but I tried to set a delay on the focus(), and it does nothing.  What is interesting, is I have other links on the opener window which when clicked set the phone number on the child window properly, it's just there is no focus back to the child.  Any help is appreciated.